# Loading data from api to tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview

I need to load a large set of messages from my backend api to a tableview for an IOS chat app.Each time I reload the data the whole list is populated.How to do this more effectively without loading the whole list ? I would like to load the last 20 messages and when the user scrolls up would like to fetch the next 20(last 40 messages) from the backend. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: One (reasonably simple) approach is to do what the iOS messages app does - Have a static cell at the top that says "load more messages".  When the user taps this cell, issue your fetch in the background. When the data is retrieved insert the new messages into your table data store array and refresh the table.

Comment: Thanks Paul.Will Try that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know how exactly to go about this. But i would imagine it that you would call the API from

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

in that way it would call the api every time a cell is on screen. the problem with this approach how ever is that you will be calling the api every time a cell goes in and out of screen.

Comment: @ Khalid, I  call the api at the viewdidload  where the messages are put into an NSMutableArray and when a new message comes I reload the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can do pagination. If you know how many rows are present at a time, you can figure out the offset and call the API once the rows pass a n*limit - 1. Example: limit of 10, you fetch every time a user sees the 9th, 19th, 29th row. It gives a 1 row buffer to load the next 10 rows.

You can even get fancier and from the speed of scrolling, adjust how aggressive you are with pre-fetching.